Сколько операций существует в математике?
Можно ли считать операциями такие действия, как интегрирование и
дифференцирование? Под математическими операциями я затрагиваю сложение, вычитание,умножение, деление, степень и другие. В смысле "операция" я говорю и про бинарные и про унарные и про логические и даже операторы сравнения и арифметические.

Сколько придумаете, столько и будет, для ответа на свой вопрос изучайте теорию групп.

Так разделов математики много. И в каждом разделе математики могут быть свои операции. И со временем в математике появляются всё новые области. Так что это живая наука.

Из Википедии:

Операция f — отображение, областью определения которого является прямое произведение нескольких множеств. Математически операцию можно записать как отображение

(B и A могут совпадать), где n называется арностью операции.

Вывод: операций в математике бесконечное количество...

Бесконечно. Интегрирование и дифференцирование - это как бы функции над функциями.
